# Cannot run Roblox linux wrapper

Tags: linux, roblox

im on Fedora 34 and i followed a tutorial for roblox on linux https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ve9xRgOKb_Y&t=155s
and if i then finally try to run roblox-linux-wrapper/rlw and select the wine binary file everything like in the tutorial but then if i try to click install/reinstall it gives theese errors

```
0114:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0114:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
```

and it spams it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved it, the problem was i needed a custom wine version. You can get it from the Grapejuice Enthusiasts discord.